# Ruby on Rails full calendar gem ActionView::Template:Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fullcalendar, actionview

I've been working on a ruby on rails app and trying to integrate the full calender gem but am experiencing errors. I can get the calendar to display but not the module to display to enter new events, every time I fix an error I seem to run into another.

I'm currently getting an ActionView::Template::Error

In my console

```
Started GET "/entries/new?_=1492426544714" for ::1 at 2017-04-17 11:55:52 +0100
Processing by EntriesController#new as JS
  Parameters: {"_"=>"1492426544714"}
  Rendered entries/_form.html.erb (46.9ms)
  Rendered entries/_new.html.erb (78.2ms)
  Rendered entries/new.js.erb (109.6ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 141ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `entries_index_path' for #<#<Class:0x61746a8>:0x9f321c0>):
    1: <%= simple_form_for @entry, remote: true do |f| %>
    2:   <div class="form-inputs">
    3:     <%= f.input :title %>
    4:     <%= f.input :date_range, input_html: { class: "form-control input-sm date-range-picker" } %>
  app/views/entries/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_entries__form_html_erb___640013074_85163292'
  app/views/entries/_new.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_entries__new_html_erb__917401192_85193628'
  app/views/entries/new.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_entries_new_js_erb__613427356_85255440'


  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.text.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.text.erb (78.1ms)
```

new.js.erb

```
$('#remote_container').html('<%= j render "new" %>');
$('#new_entry').modal('show');
```

_new.html.erb

```
<div class="modal fade" id="new_entry">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Create New Event</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <%= render 'form', entry: @entry %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It is a Rails magic, when you don't specify second option(`url`) for `simple_form_for`, Rails try to set it, in your case `<%= simple_form_for @entry do |f|%>` converts by Rails to `<%= simple_form_for @entry, url: entries_index_path do |f|%>`. In your routes, there is no such `_path` helper(as error says). 
To resolve this issue run `bundle rake routes` and set the right `url` option.

[`Check the documentation`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for)